# Is it possible to download an older version of an app if you purchased a newer one on a different phone using the same Apple ID?

Tags: iphone, applications, ios-appstore, apple-id, apple-store

I have an app that I want to download but it requires iOS 11.3 or higher. That app has been available since iOS 9 and older versions are compatible with 9 and 10.

Some apps which similarly require iOS 11+ that are in my purchased apps list enable me to download an older version of that app but the ones which i have not purchased don't. They just say that i require iOS 11.3 or higher.

Is it possible to sign into my apple ID on a different iPhone running iOS 11.3 or higher, download the app so that it appears in my purchased list and then sign out, go back to my iPhone and download the app in it's older version like the rest of the apps?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Does the developer of that app have a version available on the App Store that will run with an older version?  It's up to each developer to determine if they want to support older iOS versions.  Sometimes a developer will remove the older versions from the App Store because they no longer work properly.

Comment: @fsb I don't know that. It's not a game or anything performance-draining, so probably it has an older version. If the app has an older version available would the scenario in which i try to download it the first time with an older iOS still result in me getting a message saying i need to upgrade? If so, would the method i described "trick the system" into allowing me to get the older version from my purchased list? Other apps do but im worried if that's only because i already HAD that older version prior to the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, this is possible but it depends on the developer.** The developer of the iOS app must enable the feature on Apple's App Store.

See [How can I make allow users with older versions of iOS to download an older version of my app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254172/).

You may want to contact the developer to ask them directly.

Comment: It works if the developer has an older version on the app store. I just tried it and i was able to download the older version on my current iPhone even though i downloaded a newer one using a different iPhone.

Comment: It only works if the app developer has allowed older versions to be downloaded.  If you can't do it with the app you're asking about you'll need to contact the developer.